# Rate of change with possible negative numbers

Tags: c#, math, decimal, negative-number

I feel really stupid about this but I'm having some problems with calculating the change in % when working with negative numbers.

The calculation I'm using gives a satisfying result when the numbers are > 0.

```
decimal rateOfChange = (newNumber - oldNumber) / Math.Abs(oldNumber);
```

1. Lets say I have two numbers 0.476(newNumber) and -0.016(oldNumber) that's an increase of 0.492 and with **my** calculation the rate of change is 3 075%.
2. If i instead have 0.476(newNumber) and 0.001(oldNumber) that's an increase of 0.475 and **my** calculation will give me the rate of change of 47 500% which seems correct.

Blue line represent example one and red line is example two. In my world blue line should have bigger % change.

How would I write this calculation to give me the correct % change when also dealing with negative numbers? I want it to handle both increases and decreases in the % change.

**I understand this is a math issue and I need to work on my math**

[image: Blue line is first example & Red line second example]

Comment: One way: `((oldNumber >=0) ? newNumber - oldNumber : newNumber + oldNumber)`

Comment: It is just not a very meaningful calculation if the numbers are allowed to get close to 0, 1/x is highly non-linear.  You'd get ahead if you have a meaningful minimum and maximum value so you can divide by (max - min).  Or you also record, say, the time at which the numbers are recorded so you can divide by the time interval.

Comment: You are mixing two concepts: absolute deviation and *relative* deviation. Relative is ... well *relative* and you are referring it to the magnitude of the old value. Positive or negative values don't really matter.

Comment: Ok, so how do i fix it? I want the rate of change between two numbers - how hard can it be? :)

Comment: @rickard you don't, the way you are doing it is correct.

Comment: This is by now actually a pure maths question, as the programming layer has no influence on this problem, and as such has become off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me.

```
decimal newNumber = 0.476m;
decimal oldNumber = -0.016m;
decimal increase = newNumber - oldNumber; // this is 0.492 which is true
decimal rateOfChange = increase / Math.Abs(oldNumber);
```

`rateOfChange` is equal to approximately 30.75 which is 3075% which is the correct change.

The second example works too. The `increase` is -0.475 which gives the `rateOfChange` equal to -475 which is equal to -47500% which is correct.

Comment: You have swapped the values of newNumber & oldNumber from my example. My issue is when the oldNumber is negative.

My second example was just to show that the percentage change from example One should be alot higher than the percentage change from example Two. The difference is higher so the % change should also be higher.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I switched them and corrected the answer. Well in that case it is working as expected. The increase is calculated properly and so is the percentage of change. I don't see any problem with the results you are getting - they are correct. The percentage in the second example is higher as it should.

Comment: No, read the examples again. The difference(%) in the first example should be higher?

Comment: Yeah i guess it's my math skills that are bad. Thank you for taking your time

Comment: I added a picture to describe my confusion. In my world the blue line would be a bigger % change than red line.

Comment: Well the lines show absolute change. But in your equation you divide by the original value which makes it a change relative to the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two concepts: absolute and relative deviation.

You seem to expect that bigger absolute deviations imply bigger relative deviations, which is false. You also seem to think that negative numbers is the cause of the unexpected (but correct) results you are getting.

Relative deviation depends on the magnitude of the absolute deviation *and* the magnitude of your reference value, not its sign. You can have smaller absolute deviations that imply really big relative deviations and vice versa.

```
old value: 1
new value: 100
abs. deviation: 99
rel. deviation: 99

old value: .00001
new value: 1
abs deviation: .99999
rel deviation: 99999
```

Comment: Ok, it's my limitations in math that's the problem then. For me it would be logical that the % change between my first example would be bigger than the second example. I need to read more about what you are explaining i guess.

Comment: @rickard it all depends on what reference value you consider. If you happen to take the *new* value as the reference then the relative deviation will behave as you expect. But you are *changing* the reference value so you are really comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: I always want the new value to be the reference. If old value is less than new value it's an increase(since new value is higher). If old value is higher than new value it's an decrease. (new value) should be the reference.

Comment: @rickard No, that's simply what defines the sign of your absolute deviation, the reference value I'm referring to is what you divide the absolute deviation by (`Math.Abs(oldValue)` in your code). Think of it this way: relative deviation is the number of reference values that added together produce the absolute deviation. Given an absolute deviation, the smaller your reference value is, the bigger your relative deviation is because you need to add more of them together to reach the absolute deviation.

Comment: Thank you for your time - i need to go back to school :)

Comment: I added a picture to describe my confusion. In my world the blue line would be a bigger % change than red line.

Comment: Don't feel too bad. The confusion is a known problem. Here is a great explanation: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3986352/141182

Comment: Thank you, @juanmirocks.  Never saw that answer.  Very well written, indeed.